# 18.04: Fixing video lag

Tags: 18.04, display

I just bought a dirt cheap PC, installed Ubuntu 18.04,and want to use it for the living room TV.

The problem is when running YouTube videos with lots of action, it seems like the stop half of the screen is lagging behind the bottom part of the screen by just a fraction of a second. It is  annoying to watch, so I want to know if you folks had some possible solutions.

A) The lag doesnt go away. B) no only firefox, where i play it. C) i am using youtube to play it.  product: SVE1513Q1ESI (54527900)
        *-display
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

Comment: A possible solution is to buy a better computer.

Comment: A) When you downsize the Youtube window to progressively smaller windows, does the lag go away? B) Are you running anything else at the same time? C) Are you using VLC or some other app to play the video? D) Please run 
_sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo lshw | grep display && sudo lspci -v -s $(lspci | grep ' VGA ' | cut -d" " -f 1)_ 
, highlight the resulting text, copy the text with Ctrl-Shift-C then return here, click [edit], and paste the result in the question so we can see what video you have. You may need to add a video card, but let's see what you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: A) The lag doesnt go away. B) no ony firefox, where i play it. C) i am using youtube to play it.